# can I convert Media Object from ionic to Blob?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I try to convert a MediaObject recorded in Ionic to a Blob , and I didnt success.
Does anyone know how to do that?

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/

```
audio: MediaObject = this.media.create('test.mp3');
```

Comment: Can you add some code please?

Comment: Did you try  

    this.audioBlob = new Blob([this.audio], {type: 'audio/mp3'});

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the path to the file first, then convert it into a blob.

1. Get file path:

To avoid a couple iOS quirks, I use the file plugin's `createFile()` method to create a temp file first. It returns a promise that resolves to a path which you need to convert to a cordova (CDV) file path via the `toInternalURL()` method. The media object is created after the temp file is created. It should not have the `"file://"` prefix. e.g.

```
this.filePlugin.createFile(this.file.tempDirectory, YOUR_FILE_NAME, true).then(filePath => { 
    audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.file.tempDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '') + YOUR_FILE_NAME);
    // your recording logic here...
    // once the recording is finished:
    cdvPath = filePath.toInternalURL(); 
}
```

2. Once you're done recording, we use the path to create a blob via the following function. Call it with `cdvPath` obtained above and you're done. (*PAY ATTENTION TO THE FACT THAT IT RESOLVES TO AN OBJECT!*):

```
makeFileIntoBlob(_filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fileName, fileExtension = "";
        this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(_filePath)
            .then(fileEntry => {
                let {name, nativeURL} = fileEntry;
                // get the path..
                let path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
                fileName = name;
                // if you already know the file extension, just assign it to           // variable below
                fileExtension = fileName.match(/\.[A-z0-9]+$/i)[0].slice(1);
                // we are provided the name, so now read the file into a buffer
                return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, name);
            })
            .then(buffer => {
                // get the buffer and make a blob to be saved
                let medBlob = new Blob([buffer], {
                    type: `audio/${fileExtension}`
                });

                // pass back blob and the name of the file for saving
                // into fire base
                resolve({ blob: medBlob, blobName: name});
            })
            .catch(e => reject(e));
    });
}
```